# mysql error with column being null

Tags: mysql

Below is the query I am trying to execute, and it throws `1048 Column 'sub_order_id' cannot be null` error. So I checked the tables and both `order_products_boxes` and `orders_products` tables seem to have data against `sub_order_id='22861-1R'`, so any idea why i am still getting the error?

```
SELECT Upper(Ifnull(op.supplier_payment_method, ''))                        AS
       Payment_Method,
       op.supplier_payment_date                                             AS
       Payment_Date,
       Date_format(Ifnull(op.supplier_payment_date, op.ship_date), '%M %Y') AS
       Payment_Month,
       'B&H'                                                                AS
       Farm,
       op.sub_order_id                                                      AS
       Order_num,
       Date_format(op.ship_date, '%b-%d-%Y')                                AS
       Ship_Date,
       op.farm_credit                                                       AS
       Farm_Credit,
       op.credit_memo                                                       AS
       Credit_Memo,
       op.credit_description                                                AS
       Credit_Description,
       opb.boxes                                                            AS
       Box_Type,
       Concat('$', Format(op.box_charge, 2))                                AS
       Box_Charge,
       op.invoice_num                                                       AS
       Invoice_num,
       Concat('$', Format(op.invoice_amt, 2))                               AS
       Invoice_Amt,
       Concat('$', Format(op.total_invoice_amt, 2))                         AS
       Total_Invoice_Amt,
       Concat(op.um_qty, ' ', op.um_type)                                   AS
       St_Bu_Qty,
       op.po_product_name                                                   AS
       Invoice_desc,
       Concat('$', Format(( op.price_um * op.um_qty ), 2))                  AS
       Cost_product_cms,
       op.supplier_invoice_note                                             AS
       Supplier_Invoice_Notes,
       Concat('$', Format(op.cms_invoice_cost, 2))                          AS
       CMS_Invoice_diff,
       Concat('$', Format(op.total_farm_cost, 2))                           AS
       Farm_Cost
FROM   orders_products op
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT sub_order_id,
Group_concat(Concat(box_type_qty, ' ', bo.box_option_name)
                          SEPARATOR
                                    ', ') AS
boxes
FROM   order_products_boxes opb
INNER JOIN box_options bo
        ON bo.id = opb.box_type_id
WHERE  opb.sub_order_id = '22861-1R') opb
ON opb.sub_order_id = op.sub_order_id
WHERE  op.sub_order_id = '22861-1R'
ORDER  BY op.ship_date DESC
```

Comment: Is that part of an `INSERT` statement?

Comment: No, this is just a select query

Comment: Question....if you delete that field from the query....the query works isnt if??

Answer (score 0):

```
Description:
null values in selected columns for left side of join cause error:
"1048 column 'name' cannot be null"
```

so guess its the row
ON opb.sub_order_id = op.sub_order_id

that don't like whne op.sub_order_id is null

the where is tested after the join

you can try:

```
ON opb.sub_order_id = COALESCE(op.sub_order_id, -1)
```

Comment: Why would `NULL` values in the left side of a join cause an error?

Comment: don't know, just found that explaination when i googled, and if its true, you can try and see if that rows fix it

Comment: Which page did you find this?